# Android WebView: A particular site doesn't render properly.

Tags: java, android, webview

I am working with a WebView which is supposed to open any website.
I have 2 activities-CallingActivity and UrlBrowser. The webview is in UrlBrowser.
The CallingActivity has an EditText which takes the URL from a user and supplies it to the UrlBrowser activity via a bundle object passed as an extra with an Intent object. The UrlBrowser activity uses this URL to load into a webview.

I have to update a progress bar with the loading progress also for which I've used the onProgressChanged method to update values .

The problem I'm facing is that a particular website: www.flipkart.com is not rendering properly. A blank light brownish patch is all that is visible in the webview.

I tried changing the user agent of the WebView. On putting the user agent string of a desktop chrome browser all websites including flipkart opened perfectly, however, their desktop versions opened. I need the mobile version. As soon as I revert to using the user agent of a mobile browser, the same problem occurs. This led me to believe that maybe something is wrong with the user agents so I faked the user agent to chrome's user agent and the problem still persisted.
Here is the code for the two activities and other relevant files:

UrlBrowser.Java

```
    public class UrlBrowser extends AppCompatActivity
    {


    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String finalUrl;
    Context appcontext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_url_browser);
        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        Bundle b= getIntent().getExtras();
        String finalUrl="http://"+b.getString("url");
        appcontext=getApplicationContext();
        viewPage(finalUrl);

    }
    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                Toast.makeText(appcontext,"Waiting for "+url ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void viewPage(String url)
    {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.ge    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data"+getPackageName()+"/cache");
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
           }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_url_browser, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

CallingActivity.java

```
    public class CallingActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button goButton;
    EditText urlField;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calling);
        goButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.goButton);
        urlField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.urlField);
    }
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String url=urlField.getText().toString();
        Intent i=new Intent(this,UrlBrowser.class);
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putString("url",url);
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_calling, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this? Any help appreciated

Comment: Does that site render correctly if you visit it from the stock browser?

Comment: Yes, it runs perfectly

Comment: What version of Android are you running on?  WebView [changed in 4.4 to be based on Chromium](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)... but if you're pre-4.4 than that could explain the differences you're seeing..

Comment: I have 4.4.2 installed on my phone.

Comment: The minimum sdk version that I've set is API 19

Comment: did you find a solution ??

Comment: Same problem here...